# Word for spelling words as pronounced using the alphabet not IPA

Tags: single-word-requests

Phonetic spelling is when you spell words using IPA. Is it also called the same when you use alphabet? Just like this:

pronunciation [pruh-nuhn-see-ey-shuh n]

Comment: My nam iz stew im in furst grad

Comment: Dug out our 1973 Merriam-Webster dictionary.  One definition of "phonetic" is *constituting an alteration of ordinary spelling that better represents the spoken language, that employs only characters of the regular alphabet, and that is used in a context of conventional spelling.*  By that definition IPA isn't fonetic.